# VB Entering a Non_Numeric value crashes the program

Tags: vba

Please consider adding a description to this question to attract more helpful responses.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub BtnCalculateRevenue_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnCalculateRevenue.Click
        Dim intvalue As Integer = CInt(TxtInputClassA.Text)
        Dim intvalue2 As Integer = CInt(TxtInputClassB.Text)
        Dim intvalue3 As Integer = CInt(TxtinputClassC.Text)
        Dim total As Double
        Try
            LblStatus.Text = String.Empty

            LblClassAResult.Text = (intvalue * 15).ToString("c")
            LblClassBResult.Text = (intvalue2 * 12).ToString("c")
            LblClassCResult.Text = (intvalue3 * 9).ToString("c")
            total = CDbl((intvalue * 15) + (intvalue2 * 12) + (intvalue3 * 9))
            LblTotal.Text = total.ToString("c")
        Catch
            LblStatus.Text = "Please Enter a Number"
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnExit.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnClear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnClear.Click
        TxtInputClassA.Clear()
        TxtInputClassB.Clear()
        TxtinputClassC.Clear()
        LblClassAResult.Text = String.Empty
        LblClassBResult.Text = String.Empty
        LblClassCResult.Text = String.Empty
        LblTotal.Text = String.Empty
    End Sub
End Class
```

VB Entering a Non_Numeric value crashes the program

Comment: VBA and VB.NET are different languages with similar syntax. The descriptions of the tags for each explicitly state not to use them for the other. Don't spam tags.

Comment: My bad I accidentally clicked vba.net instead of vba. Thank you for telling me

Comment: There's no such thing as VBA.NET and that code doesn't look like VBA. I'm not sure that you even know what language you're writing code in.

Answer (score 2):

Validation is built right into Windows Forms so you should make use of it. If you want to force the user to enter numbers in each of three `TextBoxes` then you can do this:

```vb
Private Sub TextBoxes_Validating(sender As Object, e As ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles TextBox3.Validating, TextBox2.Validating, TextBox1.Validating
    Dim tb = DirectCast(sender, TextBox)

    If Not Integer.TryParse(tb.Text, Nothing) Then
        'Select all the invalid text and highlight it.
        tb.SelectAll()
        tb.HideSelection = False

        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a whole number",
                        "Invalid Input",
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                        MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)

        'Remove highlight when TextBox is not focused.
        tb.HideSelection = True

        'Don't let the control lose focus while data is invalid.
        e.Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If ValidateChildren() Then
        'All data is valid  so proceed.
        Dim n1 = CInt(TextBox1.Text)
        Dim n2 = CInt(TextBox2.Text)
        Dim n3 = CInt(TextBox3.Text)

        '...
    End If
End Sub
```

The `ValidateChildren` method will raise the `Validating` event for every control on the form and return `False` if any fail validation, i.e. `e.Cancel` is set to `True` in any event handlers, so that ensures that even controls that never received focus will be validated before the data is used.

Comment: When I add this code in I'm getting errors for Textbox3, TextBox2, TextBox1, and Button1

Answer (score 1):

Its bombing out on your cast "`CInt(*value*)`" so you can fix the code a couple ways.  You can move your try above the casts like...

```
Try
    Dim intvalue As Integer = CInt(TxtInputClassA.Text)
    Dim intvalue2 As Integer = CInt(TxtInputClassB.Text)
    Dim intvalue3 As Integer = CInt(TxtinputClassC.Text)
    Dim total As Double
    LblStatus.Text = String.Empty
```

You can do a data validation on your inputs and exit if they aren't all numeric (put this above your Dim intvalue code)

```
    For Each value As String In {TxtInputClassA.Text, TxtInputClassA.Text, TxtInputClassA.Text}
        If Not IsNumeric(TxtInputClassA.Text) Then
            LblStatus.Text = "Please Enter a Number"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next
```

Instead of casting as an int, use the tryparse method on Int32...

```
    Dim intvalue As Integer
    If Not Int32.TryParse(TxtInputClassA.Text, intvalue) Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
```

Or you could intercept the keypresses on each text box so that only numbers can be entered

```
Private Sub TxtInputClassA_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TxtInputClassA.KeyPress

    If Not Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) Then
        e.Handled = True
    End If

End Sub
```

You can make that routine universal and append the event handler for all three text boxes like...

```
Private Sub EnforceOnlyNumericKeyPresses(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TxtInputClassA.KeyPress, TxtInputClassB.KeyPress, TxtInputClassC.KeyPress

    If Not Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) Then
        e.Handled = True
    End If

End Sub
```

Choose your favorite or do all of them, lots of choices.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your textboxes with NumericUpDown controls and retrieve their .Value for your calculation. NUDs don't allow non numeric input and can have a fixed number of decimal places which may also be useful in a financial context

Comment: When I Replace the TextBoxes with NumericUpDown controls I get an error with TxtInputClassA.Clear()
TxtInputClassB.Clear()
TxtinputClassC.Clear() saying that 'Clear' is not a member of 'NumericUpDown'

Comment: @Wolffpup, so put some thought into how you might clear `NumericUpDown` controls. They are different controls so they work differently. Make the effort to find out how they do work.